# spring 3 uploadify giving 404 Error

Tags: spring-mvc, uploadify

I am using Spring 3 and implementing Uploadify. The problem is, the files are updating properly but it is giving HTTP Error 404, on completion of file upload. I tried every possible solution, but none of them works.

The files are uploaded. Values are storing in DB properly, only that i am getting HTTP Error 404. Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance.

**The Solution is :**

```
Finally i found the solution but it is lame.

I removed the return "" and changed the method as void. Thats it.

But still i don't understand why the same code is working in Spring 2.5.6 and not in 3.
```

**The URL of the screenshot** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBjiK.jpg

**The JSP Page**

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'scripts/uploadify.swf',            
        'fileObjName' : 'the_file',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png',         
        'multi'    : true,          
        'uploader' : '/photo/savePhoto',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '10MB',
        'uploadLimit' : 50, 
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {  
            $('#file_upload').uploadify('settings', 'formData', {'trip_id' :'1', 'trip_name' :'Sample Trip', 'destination_trip' :'Mumbai','user_id' :'1','email' :'s@s.com','city_id' :'12'});  
            },
        'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
            console.log('queueData : '+queueData);
            window.location.href = "trip/details/1";
        }
    });
});
```

**The Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="photo/{action}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postHandler(@PathVariable("action") String action, HttpServletRequest request) {
if(action.equals("savePhoto"))
{   
        try{
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
    MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile("the_file");
    String trip_id = request.getParameter("trip_id");
    String trip_name = request.getParameter("trip_name");
    String destination_trip = request.getParameter("destination_trip");
    String user_id = request.getParameter("user_id");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String city_id = request.getParameter("city_id");
        photo.savePhoto(file,trip_id,trip_name,destination_trip,user_id,email,city_id);
    photo.updatetrip(photo_id,trip_id);
    }catch(Exception e ){e.printStackTrace();}
}
return "";
} **Solution** : Change the method return type as void and remove the return
```

**spring config**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver">
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

**Web.xml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>project_name</display-name>
  <distributable/>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/project_name-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jdbc.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>project_name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>project_name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you simply haven't page `trip/details/1` in your application?

EDIT:

Change `window.location.href = "trip/details/1";` to

```
 window.location.href = "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/trip/details/1";
```

Comment: trip/details is there. it is redirecting to the page also, but once upload is 100%, it is giving HTTP Error 404.

Comment: So, it mean you go to page what is not exists. I know how to check it. Please post url from what you upload photo (copy-paste from browser) and url when you get 404 error.

Comment: @user1516873 I mean once the upload is 100% done, it is giving me the error and then it is redirecting to the "trip/details/1", that mean onQueueComplete action is triggering properly. My only concern is, why it is giving "404" Error. Please click on this url to see what exactly i am telling (http://imgur.com/bf3qo).

Comment: ok, i see. So my answer is incorrect. You can run your example under firebug and find what causes 404.

Comment: Have you seen the image URL i attached?

Comment: Yeah, i have. Try to check with firebug what exactly request return 404. If it is request to `/photo/savePhoto` try to change code in your servlet, in order to manually return some valid http status, for example, before `return "";` write `response.setStatus(200);`. You should add `HttpServletResponse response` as parameter of servlet in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> The files are uploaded. Values are storing in DB properly, only that i
>   am getting HTTP Error 404.

What this tells me is that your request is properly being submitted to the URL at `'/photo/*'`
and is properly handled by the postHandler() method.

You're getting a 404 because your web application doesn't know what to do with the url of `""` that the `postHandler()` method is trying to direct you to.

There is most likely (and I'm making some assumptions here, it'd be helpful if you included the web.xml) a request mapper not set up to handle the " " that your controller is returning; make your controller return some sort of meaningful view name that has a valid servlet mapping and you will not get a 404.

Comment: Updated the main post, and added web.xml. This exact same code is working fine with Spring 2.5.6 and url looks like this PhotoAction.do?action=savePhoto and other codes are same. This is the thing which i am unable to find what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I added "@ResponseBody" and got the right result.
I think the problem is that without the annotation "@ResponseBody", the returned string is handled by some strange resolver and javascript code gets response of unexpected form.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String upload(HttpServletResponse response,
                        HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
```